# SICP exercise 3.62

Tags: scheme, sicp

I've been finished exercise 3.59, 3.60, 3.61 and get stuck at 3.62, So I turn to [sicp-solutions@scheme wiki community](http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-solutions) for help.

Exercise 3.59 and 3.60 could be tested easily with `sine` and `cosine` case, but not 3.61 or 3.62.

The 3.62 code provided on the community produces all-zero `tangent` series on condition of correct `sine` and `cosine` series:

```
> (display-stream-until sine-series 7)
0
1
0
-1/6
0
1/120
0

> (display-stream-until cosine-series 7)
1
0
-1/2
0
1/24
0
-1/720

> (display-stream-until tangent-series 7)
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

At first I think the code I wrote in previous exercises might be wrong, So I check my solutions of 3.59/3.60/3.61 with that on the community and it turn out we produce the same result.

I try copying the code of [3.59](http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-ex-3.59)/[3.60](http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-ex-3.60)/[3.61](http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-ex-3.61) into my IDE(DrRacket) and still the `tangent` series is printed with all zero.

Here is the code:

```
(define (mul-series s1 s2)
  (cons-stream (* (stream-car s1)
                  (stream-car s2))
               (add-streams (mul-streams (stream-cdr s1)
                                         (stream-cdr s2))
                            (mul-series s1 s2))))

(define (reciprocal-series s)
  (cons-stream 1
               (scale-stream (mul-series (stream-cdr s)
                                         (reciprocal-series s))
                             -1)))

(define (div-series s1 s2)
  (let ((c (stream-car s2)))
    (if (= c 0)
        (error "constant term of s2 can't be 0!")
        (scale-stream
         (mul-series s1
                     (reciprocal-series (scale-stream s2
                     (/ 1 c))))
     (/ 1 c)))))

(define tangent-series
  (div-series sine-series
              cosine-series))
```

And its requiring part: (too long to highlight with the body)

```
(require (only-in "myLib.rkt"
                  cons-stream
                  stream-car
                  stream-cdr
                  add-streams
                  mul-streams
                  scale-stream
                  stream-map
                  ones
                  integers
                  sine-series
                  cosine-series
                  stream-ref
                  display-stream-until))
```

Could somebody tell me what's wrong with my code or where might the possible bugs hide?

By the way, how do your guys verify your code on SICP?

I've found several blog/github repository that provide code without (**enough**) testing case(s).

I have hard time dealing with such mathematics questions with bare code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `mul-series`.
The product of the series [a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>x + ...] and the series [b<sub>0</sub> + b<sub>1</sub>x + ...] is
    [a<sub>0</sub>b<sub>0</sub> + (a<sub>0</sub>b<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>b<sub>0</sub>)x + ...]
but your `mul-series` produces
    (cons-stream a<sub>0</sub>b<sub>0</sub> (add-streams (mul-streams (cdr s1) (cdr s2)) (mul-series s1 s2)))
     = (cons-stream a<sub>0</sub>b<sub>0</sub> (add-streams [a<sub>1</sub>b<sub>1</sub>, ...] [a<sub>0</sub>b<sub>0</sub>, ...]))
     = [a<sub>0</sub>b<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>b<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>b<sub>0</sub>, ...]

You can check `mul-series` using the identity sin(x)<sup>2</sup> + cos(x)<sup>2</sup> = 1 (as suggested in Exercise 3.60).
Some other simple test cases to try are
    [2] * [0 + x] = [0 + 2x]
    [1 + x] * [1 + x] = [ 1 + 2x + 1x<sup>2</sup>]

With the appropriate helper functions, your tests could look like this:

```
> (show-series (add-streams (mul-series sine-series sine-series) (mul-series cosine-series cosine-series)))
1 + 0*x + 0*x^2 + ...
> (show-series (mul-series (make-series '(2)) (make-series '(0 1))))
0 + 2*x + ...
> (show-series (mul-series (make-series '(1 1)) (make-series '(1 1))))
1 + 2*x + 1*x^2 + ...
```

Here are the helper functions I've defined:

```
(define zeroes (cons-stream 0 zeroes))

;; make-series takes a list of numbers and returns an infinite stream
;; with those numbers followed by 0's
(define (make-series coeffs)
  (if (null? coeffs)
      zeroes
      (cons-stream (car coeffs) (make-series (cdr coeffs)))))

;; show-stream prints the first 10 items in a stream
(define (show-stream stream)
  (begin (show-stream-helper stream 10)))

(define (show-stream-helper stream n)
  (if (= 0 n)
      (begin (display "...")
             (newline))
      (begin (display (stream-car stream))
             (display ", ")
             (show-stream-helper (stream-cdr stream) (- n 1)))))

;; show-series is like show-stream, but uses the format a0 + a1*x + ...
(define (show-series stream)
  (show-series-helper stream 0 10))

(define (show-series-helper stream n m)
  (if (> n m)
      (begin (display "...")
             (newline))
      (begin (show-monomial (stream-car stream) n)
             (display " + ")
             (show-series-helper (stream-cdr stream) (+ 1 n) m))))

;; show-monomial displays a*x^n
(define (show-monomial coeff pow)
  (cond
   ((= 0 pow)
    (display coeff))
   ((= 1 pow)
    (display coeff)
    (display "*x"))
   (else
    (display coeff)
    (display "*x^")
    (display pow))))
```

Comment: I'm confused on your code:`(mul-series sine-series sine-series)`, Did you leave out the `x` part (x, x^2, x^3 ...)?

Comment: The `sine-series` is a stream with the numbers [0, 1, 0, -1/6, ...] representing the power series [0 + 1*x + 0*x^2 + (-1/6)*x^3 + ...]. The x's are implicit. The result of `(mul-series sine-series sine-series)` is a stream with the coefficients of the power series of sin(x)^2. It can be shown that sin(x)^2 = x^2 + (-1/3)*x^4 + (2/45)*x^6 + ... so `(mul-series sine-series sine-series)` returns the stream [0, 0, 1, 0, -1/3, 0, 2/45, ...].

Comment: My helper function `show-series` is like `display-stream`, except it prints everything on one line and uses `*x^n` to remind us that each number in the stream represents a coefficient in the power series.

Comment: I guess I messed `mul-streams` with `mul-series`